# Xamarin Forms Shell, float view on top of all other views

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.shell

We are currently using Shell navigation within a Xamarin Forms app, and have an ask to implement a live video support functionality similar to FaceTime (but within our app).

Is it possible to float a “partial view” over the top of all pages of the app (to show the support video feed as the user continues to navigate) without having to redraw/reconnect in on every page change?

If so, how would we approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find an answer to this.

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

This package has a fantastic set of popup options which allowed us to achieve exactly what we needed (popup floating on top of the entire app). Various options also available re: enable / disable input etc.

Comment: Here is a nice video about Popup https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-uAHgf0VXs&t=1134s&ab_channel=GeraldVersluis

Answer (score 0):

Use AbsoluteLayout or RelativeLayout, they can set control based on x and y.

For more information, check the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. My understanding of these is that they are used to layout within a content page. I’m looking to have something “always on top” as the user navigates between all content pages within the app. Can you elaborate on how I achieve this by using the absolute / relative layout?

Comment: I think it's has to be implemented on native platform. Shell can not support this feature.